# Exclude a view from master layout?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have `login.blade.php` in `views/users/` that I would like to exclude from the master layout that I have.

Instead I want the login page to be a standalone page with just the login form on it.

How may I achieve that?

Answer (score 4):

Use a different layout for login page:

File `app/views/login.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.standalone')

@section('content')
   ...
@stop
```

And for your other pages:

File `app/views/home.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
   ...
@stop
```

And here your layouts:

File `app/views/layouts/standalone.blade.php`:

```
<html>
   <body>
      This is a master layout

      @yield('content')
   </body> 
</html>
```

File `app/views/layouts/master.blade.php`:

```
<html>
   <body>
      This is a standalone layout

      @yield('content')
   </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I did what you suggested but I'm still seeing the header and sidebar on the login page which belong to the main master layout. This is the [Login Master Layout](http://pastebin.com/DPbUjE2z) and this is the [Login View](http://pastebin.com/VSKY9qaF)

Comment: Must be something in your layout or view. Smartadmin is pretty huge, I use it here too. Start with something smaller, remove all of those smartadmin html and css, just to test, leaving only a basic html,  form and inputs, then add markup progressively.