# exclude certain part using layout of laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a layout blade file it has `@include('footer')`

but in one page I came across this issue : I want to extend that layout but did not want to include the footer.

So what should I do? Is there any way I can check what page is using the layout file in my layout.blade.php?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude a view from master layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987271/exclude-a-view-from-master-layout)

Comment: Indeed, see Tiger's link tot the duplicate question for your answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can define a section in your layout:

```
@section('footer')
    @include('footer')
@show
```

And then override it in one view:

```
@section('footer')
{{-- this section will be empty --}}
@stop
```

Answer (score 1):

Posting this in case anyone still has this problem. One idea is to create a separate master layout that does not include a footer, and extend from there.

Comment: Please share more details about this

Comment: Apologies if the answer was not clear. Say he has many pages that extend master.blade.php (with footer). If you now want a special page that uses most of master but excluding the footer, you can create a copy of master (call it master_no_footer.blade.php) and remove footer. Then the special page can extend from here